# How to keep UWP app data refreshed in background without having UWP app opened?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I am trying to figure out how a UWP app can keep its data updated **without having to be in foreground at all times**.

For example, imagine an UWP app that is getting its data from somewhere.  That data may change meaning that the UWP app will have to refresh it.  I would like to have some kind of component doing that refreshing in background regardless whether UWP app is in foreground or not (whether user is staring at it or not).

In Android, you can use non-sticky-service or pending intent for this.

On IOS, I heard you can use something called BackgroundAppRefresh.

I did some research on UWP side and I am looking at AppService and I see it can be run out-of-app process or in-app process.

However, an in-app process Windows 10 AppService will be killed if app is back-grounded (user is not staring at it).  And an out-of-app process Windows 10 AppService will run up to 30sec and then be killed  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service.

This means that my background syncing will not work since it will be stopped after maximum of 30 seconds if user is not having the UWP app in foreground (user is looking at it).

So, I concluded that Windows 10 AppService is not what I can use to implement this functionality.

How and what I can use to implement something like this in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP apps you can use BackgroundTasks to keep your app data refreshed even when the app is not actively running in the foreground.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks

Comment: Yes but they have limit and he wants something that runs for a long time...

Comment: What's the scenario you are trying to accomplish? If your activity starts in the foreground, you can use ExtendedExecution to keep running for a long time in the background. You might want to ask a new question for the specific scenario, so we can provide a specific answer.

Comment: I haven't asked the question, I've just noticed that your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I thought the original question and description are clear.  I am trying to build a UWP app that uses *something* to keep its data updated in background (background sync) even if the UWP app is not in foreground.  I know I mentioned how Android/IOS would do it and am trying to do something along the lines in UWP.  I want to avoid to have user to look at my app and wait until it finishes this background syncing.  Hope that explains, let me know what is unclear and I'll try to explain better.  Thanks again.

Comment: What is incorrect/insufficient about the backgroundtask answer? You can trigger background tasks to keep your app data refreshed even when it is not in the foreground. You can trigger them periodically, or based on push notifications or based on a number of other triggers.

Comment: I am actually in process of reading the link you provided, thanks for that.  And I see I can trigger bg-tasks but they will run up to 30 sec which seem to be same as in case of Win10 AppService.  Reply from @IvanIčin is pretty much same what I concluded which is that it can only be done on Android.  So, I am trying to figure out how to do it in UWP.

Comment: Note that the various triggers have different policies - for example the MaintananceTrigger task can run for 10min: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/use-a-maintenance-trigger  - if they are not sufficient for a particular scenario I'd like to hear that feedback. You also can log it on https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform .

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Assuming I have a a library written in C++ and wrapped in C# using SWIG and the library is being used to get data from remote.  The library provides the app (planned to be a UWP app for the next gen) with notifications.  So, I ask it to get me data and it notifies me when data is available through registered listeners/observers.  Would you still recommend looking at the same article or you have some other suggestion?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Would need to know more about the library. If it's using all UWP compliant APIs it would work in a UWP. The scenario you describe sounds very much like you want to register for push notifications, so this article might be more relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT  Thanks, I will take a look at that article as well (looots of reading these days :)).  I also found this article that has given me much clearer picture about the beast I am fighting here.  Very valuable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396   Much appreciated

Comment: ... btw, did I mention that I'll be using Xamarin.Forms for this

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT  I created new question explaining specifically what I am trying to solve at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886142/swig-c-sharp-calling-from-uwp-background-task-or-extended-execution

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible. Also your information regarding iOS isn't correct - you don't have unlimited time to refresh your app there. It is only possible on Android as it is fully open even to the extent that you may make a device unusable with your app.

There is no guaranteed way to do this on UWP. `BackgroundTask` offers only limited time to work in background which isn't fit for you. However you may use some sort of the background download APIs that don't have restrictions if your problem is in the time to download the content. If you need the time to do something else then the best solution is to ask for `ExtendedExecution` when the app is in the foreground so that it doesn't go into the background, but it may not be granted and is not granted to run forever in the foreground either.

Also of note, if you expect the app to run on the PCs the app is not in the background unless it is minimized.

Comment: What is incorrect re IOS info I provided?  I am not IOS dev but I though BackgroundAppRefresh does exactly this.  Much appreciated

Comment: BackgroundAppRefresh has some limits too. Not sure if that is 30 secs or what, but definitely you can't run as much as you want (let alone that you can't even run when you want but when system decides that is convenient and may be useful to the user).

Comment: OK, I guess then the running *forever* concept should be out of the equation.  Looks like a good idea to read the link @StefanWickMSFT provided.  Or do you have any other suggestion?  Much appreciated

Comment: As said if you need to download something in the background you might check whether background downloader may work for you. No other suggestions.

Comment: ExtendedExecution seam to be something promissing as the UWP app I am talking about is going to run on PC or tablet but as far as I understand, ExetendedExecution offers some kind of graceful cancellation in case it can not complete.  Also, as far as I understand, when ExtendedExecution is requested and execution, user does not have to use app actively (look at it).  Is this correct?

Comment: ExtendedExecution will work as long as that code is running at all, I am not sure what do you mean by 'not looking' - at least on the tablet it would mean that your app is already in the background so it is probably not running.

Comment: What I mean is that if my app is open and running and I request background sync, can I do (a) open say Gmail on top of it and write an email while the extended execution will still do what it is supposed to do and (b) minimize my app and do something else, again, say open Gmail and write an email while extended execution will do its work in background?  These 2 are what I am not clear about still.  Thanks

Comment: ... cont'd. Actually, I think I found answer to both (a) and (b) above in this article [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396] right in the 1st paragraph of "Extended Execution" section.