# SWIG - C# Calling from UWP Background Task or Extended Execution

Tags: uwp, windows-10, swig, background-task

I wonder if anyone has tried calling a swig C# wrapper around a C++ library from a UWP Background Task, Extended Execution, or Activation Trigger?

My C# swig wrapper provides functionality written in C++ which handles network calls to services such as cloud etc.  It might download or upload files such as documents, images, etc or it might just synchronize them with local on machine copies.

I have been doing lots of reading/research lately on the topic of Background Activation and Foreground Activation from a UWP app.  So far, what I have found that:

- Background Tasks can run in-and-out-of-process of the UWP app but have limitation to 25 seconds + 5 seconds of execution time.
- Background tasks with Application Trigger have limitation to 10 minutes
- Extended Execution seem to run until the background task has completed
- or...

My goal is to be able to run this application and it will initiate the library (swigged C#) which will do syncing in background.  User may or may not work directly with the application, so app can be minimized, covered by another app such as web browser (so not actively used), but the background operation will execute every 10 minutes or so to do its syncing.

Based on my reading and some great help I got so far, I am trying to find a safe path to proceed.  These 3 seem to be what I am looking at.  Which one is most applicable is still unclear to me.

Has anyone dealt with a scenario like this already that could give some good advice?

Comment: Have you looked at using MaintenanceTrigger? With this one you can run your code for up to 10min - periodically as frequently as every 15min.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I think you have mentioned it before and I looked at the very sparse documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger. The problem with MT is that it requires power connection.  So far, to me it looks like Extended Execution and Application Trigger might be something but I need something that can activate the task either by-user or automatically using various intervals, say every 5, 10, 15, 30, 60 min, 2hrs, 4hrs, ... 1ce a day,...etc

Comment: ... ... or Win 10 AppSeevice in addition to the Extended Execution and ApplicationTrigger but I think AppService has strict 30sec limit

Comment: While running on battery, Store apps aren't allowed to run extended amount of time in the background (aside from EE and AT, which are triggered from the foreground), because that would be a fast way to drain the battery and would break the Store promise of well-behaved apps. If you are not distributing through Store, you can use FullTrustProcessLauncher to launch your own background process and have full control over its lifetime. Otherwise, I'd recommend using MT and do less sync'ing when running on battery (with EE, AT and/or a TimerTrigger).

Comment: I understand that it would drain a battery but there must be some way of letting user to connect to power if the task is long running task requiring large downloads or on metered network. User can then connect to power.  So, if I understand correctly, I could use MT for a large lasting download or upload operation and EE and/or AT and/or TT for smaller downloads/uploads? ...

Comment: ... also, could you explain why AppService is not good idea for this kind of applications?  Tx

Comment: If the scenario is primarily about simple download/upload files in the background (as opposed to running actual application logic in the background) it may easiest to use the functionality from BackgroundTransfer namespace. Let we write and actual answer - please comment on the answer then as needed.

Comment: No, that is not the scenario.  The scenario is:  My UWP app starts.  It starts also a component (the above mentioned library written in C++ but swigged into C# wrapper) which then provides the UWP app with background syncing (uploads on user demands, downloads on user demand or automatic background syncing).  The module also provides UWP app with various notifications.  UWP app could be active or minimized.

Comment: Sounds like your component is a complete sync engine in itself that operates outside of the UWP app model. If you want to reuse that component instead of moving the UWP concepts explained in the answer below you have the option to launch that component via the FullTrustProcessLauncher API. However, that would only work on PC, not an other Windows 10 devices such as HoloLens, Phone or Xbox.

Comment: OK, let me read your post and go over the link, and I'll let you know if I have more question but so far, your recommendation of using MT with AT and EE seem to be what I am looking at.  I know in Android for example, I could use for this non-sticky services or pending intents, it lets me run either short or long running operation either in foreground or background and it provides ways of warning user that he may need power connection or that he is on a metered network.  I need something like that in UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file download/upload scenarios in the background you can use the BackgroundDownloader/Uploader classes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers

If you need to run long-running sync/maintenance application code tasks in the background without the app actually being run by the user, use a MaintenanceTrigger. This will allow you to run for up to 10min, as frequently as every 15min. However, this task will not run when the device is running on battery.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/use-a-maintenance-trigger

For simple sync tasks in the background when your app is not actively in use, you can use a TimeTrigger. This will also run on battery, but is limited to 30sec execution time for each run (can be scheduled every 15min).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-

If your app is in the foreground and running a synchronization activity that should continue when the app gets minimized or the screen gets locked, use an ExtendedExecutionSession:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution

If your app is in the foreground and running a synchronization activity should continue even when the user terminates the app, trigger an ApplicationTrigger background task to offload the activity to a background task:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/trigger-background-task-from-app

If the need for synchronization is a triggered from the server-side, take a look at raw push notifications to trigger your app code on the client, even when the user is not actively running your app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-raw-notification-overview

AppServices are not a solution here. An AppService is an app-to-app concept, where one app provides a service that another app consumes. This does not seem to be the case here. Btw, the lifetime of the appservice is not 30sec - it can run for as long as the consuming app is in the foreground. But again that's not applicable to your scenario here.

Comment: What is the minimum Windows / Visual Studio version requirement for these?

Comment: These all exist since the original Windows 10 release (10240). You can use VS 2015 or 2017.

Comment: Regards AppService, I still do not understand why it does not apply.  Would you mind elaborating on that?  I keep reading 2 applications communicating.  Do they have to be in foreground?  Can't I have one UI-less app periodically running (but not visible to user) and using my swigged library for syncing and reporting to my 2nd application which is the UWP application that could be in foreground or background?  Would that not be 2 apps communicating.  Sorry, just trying to understand why AppService is not applicable so I can explain it.  Tx

Comment: If you decide to launch your library in a separate process via FullTrustProcessLauncher then you can use an AppService to communicate back and forth with the UWP app process (regardless or foreground or background). My earlier point was that the AppService in itself doesn't enable your scenario, as it is primarily a means for inter-process-communication. Here is a sample that uses that mechanism: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample

Comment: O ya, I remember now.  It does not follow App store rules for well behaved app. Thanks

Comment: Stefan, but if I dont use ExtendedExecution, the code should not run if app is minimized based on documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution), 2nd paragraph.  I slightly modified MS GitHub example ExtendedExecution-Scenario1_UnspecifiedReason (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution) where instead of creating EE, I just create timer which fires OnTimer().  I would expect timer not to fire if I minimize app but I have been running it for more than 20 min powered or not.

Comment: Are you running under the debugger? We don't suspend apps while the debugger is attached. You need to test this scenario without debugger.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that explains it

Comment: So, using ExtendedExecution is probably what works for us for larger upload/download/sync operations.  I see it says that only one extended execution can be requested at a time.  Is this per application or per machine?

Comment: It's per application

Comment: By the way, if app is built in Debug mode but it is not launched from the IDE, then debugger is not attached or it is still attached?  Do I need to build app in Release mode or it is enough just not to run the app from the IDE?  The reason I am asking is that I do not see app stop processing if I minimize it.  It is built in Debug mode but I am launching it from start menu, not from the IDE.  Thanks

Comment: If you don't run from the IDE then the debugger is not attached (unless you have explicitly set it up to attach when your app starts)

Comment: Based on what I read about ExtendedExecution, it is not tied to an operation but rather just to the app (hence I guess only one is allowed per app).  Having said that, I should not have to request for it before a long lasting operation starts.  For example, image case where an operation starts and that fires a callback immediately after.  I should be able to request ExtendedExecutionSession in that callback and if allowed, my operation that started before the EE session was requested should still continue to execute if my app is minimized?

Comment: Correct, it's not tied to a particular operation, but to the app.

Comment: I assume creating, attaching event and detaching it and clearing ExtendedExecution in a static class would operate the same?  Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing situations where Revoked event is not fired and clearing of EES is not happening.  In your examples you have a long lasting operation in a method that you wrap in using a deferral but in my case I receive notifications when an operation start and when it ends (onStart, onEnd) ...

Comment: ... so I put all logic in a static class that has dictionary to track operations.  It adds operation ID in onStart and deletes it in onEnd event.  So I think I have a concurrency issue that leads to my problem because the long lasting operation is 'split' in these 2 events (cannot wrap in using deferral stmt) and onStart requests EES if it is not existing, then later onEnd deleted operation ID from dictionary and if it was the last one calls CancelExtendedExecution

Comment: You might want to start a new questions on the specific problem you are having with EE, with repro code, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I started new one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003658/uwp-extended-execution-denied-and-not-cleared